# In American English are the following three examples good to use for colon capitalization useage?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization, colons

I know that a variant of this question has been [asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/should-the-first-word-after-a-colon-be-capitalized), and recalled what my Creative writing teacher told me about when to use capitalization after a colon, by using the following three example sentences for colon usage.

> In a complete sentence, the capital case is optional.
>   1. This is what I think of cats: They steal your breath.
>
> In the following two examples, the capitalization is not optional to change, therefore the words after the colon must remain lowercase.
>
> 2. This is what I think of cats: nothing.
> 3. This is what I think of cats: scary, tiresome, snooty.

In other words, do the above examples properly illustrate proper colon and capitalization usage for American English, regardless of essay style, and usage for non-essay papers?

Comment: Not really.  Many publishers forbid a capital letter after the colon unless you would use it after a mere comma.

Comment: It's completely a matter of style. *Chicago* says to use a lowercase unless what follows the colon is a proper noun or a question—in which case use a capital. Some people use a capital letter after, others don't. In your quote (What is the source?), it makes no sense to say that one is optional while the other two are not.

Comment: @JasonBassford The source would be what I've written down verbatim from my University's Creative Writing I and II teacher from last Fall's semester. I can try sending her a email asking for the sources that she used to come to the conclusion that I wrote in my Journal during her class, but it might take some time.
And I believe that the "optional" part is a reference to the fact that, as you said, "some people use a capital letter after, others don't.".